# Perl: getting count for range of values

Tags: perl

I want to perform a count for a range of values, i.e, I have 900 values of X between 1 to 75x10^6. I need to count the number of times these X's fall in range like 1-1000000, 1000001-2000000, 2000001-3000000 ... 750 ranges, then return the counts of these ranges.

I have the values of X stored in an array so I could have done it with for loop and if..else, but giving 750 if-else's is no solution and I don't know how to implement value range in hash-keys. Please help

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Do you mean 75x10^7? Or am I counting things wrong ...

Comment: I meant 75000000 :) ...

Comment: Isn't that only 75 ranges then, not 750?

Answer (score 2):

For each value, you can subtract 1, divide by 1000000, and cut off any decimals. That gives you the index of the range as a number between 0 and 749 (inclusive).

Example:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @values = (...);  # filled from somewhere

my @range_count;
for my $value (@values) {
    my $x = int(($value - 1) / 1e6);
    $range_count[$x]++;
}
```

Now `$range_count[0]` contains the number of values in the first range, `$range_count[1]` the number of values in the second range, etc.

However, if there were no values in some range, the count will be `undef`, not 0. If this difference is important, define `@range_count` as

```
my @range_count = (0) x 750;
```

instead.